# ESD models - CDM and MM

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, resistors, esd

I am just trying to understand the differences between the ESD models in this [article](https://www.electronicdesign.com/power-management/article/21799383/whats-the-difference-between-hbm-cdm-and-mm-test).

The CDM and MM models are very similar. Is the MM model the reverse of CDM model.

I have this confusion as CDM and MM are similar in definition but their waveforms of peak current are different.

Can someone tell me what is the difference and how to understand the difference in peak current?

Answer (score 0):

If IC package picks up charge and one pin gets grounded, the charge will get discharged via that pin. This situation is a CDM event.

MM ESD event is when a charged machine comes in contact with a device and discharges through the device to ground.

So, the key difference seems to be the object that is charged.

**Edit**: As regards the peak ESD current, consider a charged capacitor that you are going to discharge. The peak discharge current is determined by the impedance connected across the capacitor to discharge it. In MM, there is a 0.5nH in that discharge path whereas in CDM, the parasitic impedance is much smaller causing a high peak.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So, only when the object is changed, why is there a difference in peak currents of the models?